# Simulate click on spacebar each 5 seconds in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to simulate a click on spacebar each 5 minutes, how can i do that , i know that the ascii code for spacebar is 32
In jQuery how i we do that ?

Comment: What is the effect of pressing on the space-bar that you are looking to happen every five minuets?

Comment: link for another page

Comment: Why wouldn't you just redirect the user to the page you want them to go to?

Comment: @JasonSperske i think im clear, have u a more interesting suggestion?

Comment: @Jason's (not me) answer looks like it would do what you are attempting, however in Firefox when I press the space bar it scrolls down a page (which the `keypress` event will not do, it is just raising an event to any listener registered).  Also your comment of "link for another page" sounds to me like you are expecting the user to be redirected (which is why I asked if just redirecting them after some interval wouldn't be easier)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plunker that demonstrates sending a keypress to an element every 750ms, but you can configure the time as appropriate

http://plnkr.co/edit/33yTNn1dKFhKMwSls5MU

Answer (score 1):

You should rather assign an event handler function to the keypress event of the control of your choice and then setup a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) that calls the same function.