# javascript / jQuery Press spacebar repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i'm trying to achieve is focus on a button and then press spacebar repeatedly, the focus part i resolved.

I searched and found this " [Simulate click on spacebar each 5 secondes in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045033/simulate-click-on-spacebar-each-5-secondes-in-jquery) " is what i want but i cant adapt it due to lack of knowledge.

I cant create buttons like they do in that example, so when the page loads the script should start and focus the button and press spacebar repeatdly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example on [that question](http://plnkr.co/edit/33yTNn1dKFhKMwSls5MU) is pretty good. 
You don't need the focus. You just need to call the button "action" function.

Here is the solution anyway, for that same example linked above:

```
var presscount = 0;
var sendEvery = 5000; //in milliseconds
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
      presscount++;
    }
    $("#output").text("The space key was pressed " + presscount + " times");
  });
     setInterval(pressKey, sendEvery);  
});

function pressKey() {
  var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
  e.which = 32; // # space
  $("#test").trigger(e);
}
```

Comment: Not possible to start automatically? i cant change anything on the page.  
  
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go!">  
  
the button is like this, if that helps.  
  
i'm not sure i understood what you said about call the button "action" function.

Comment: In my code, it starts automatically.
Notice that I removed the "start" part. calling 
`setInterval(pressKey,sendEvery)` immediatly inside the 
`$(document).ready(function() `
Everything you call here, is executed after the page is ready / loaded.

Comment: `var presscount = 0;
var sendEvery = 5000; //in milliseconds
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").on("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32) {
            presscount++;
        }
        $("#output").text("The space key was pressed " + presscount + " times");
    });
    setInterval(pressKey, sendEvery);  
});

function pressKey() {
    $('input[name=GO]').focus();
    var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    e.which = 32; // # space
    console.log("work");
    $("#test").trigger(e);
}`

Comment: i cant format my replies.... i did this cause i need to focus on that button. it indeed focus the button but never simulates the press when i add this to my tampermonkey script. Doing something wrong?

Comment: You can try to assign the trigger directly to the window, and not to "test" container, by calling  `$("window").trigger(e)` in your function.

Other thing you can try is to use the **button click** event instead of spacebar, like [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/33yTNn1dKFhKMwSls5MU)

Comment: Damm. i cant get it to work. Is there any other approach? i cant change the page since i didnt make it, i need to repeat either space bar or enter, the focus on button is a must but i have figured that. I did what you told me it focus the button like i want but never simulates the space click. I also dont need any counters, i just need to start automatically or when i press some key (q/x/t/ whatever).

Comment: Fixed with `.trigger('click');`